# Vulkan-Hpp: What is the difference between vk::UniqueHandle and vk::raii wrappers?

Tags: c++, vulkan, raii

I read the documentation of the [new raii wrappers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/blob/master/vk_raii_ProgrammingGuide.md) in the Vulkan-Hpp API.
It seems that both `vk::UniqueHandle<T>` and the raii wrappers are move only objects that destruct their handle in their destructors.

One difference seems to be is that the raii variants cannot be default constructed whereas the `UniqueHandle` ones can.

Another difference is that the raii variant seem to require the `vk::raii::Context` class to be instantiated and passed around.

So why both of them exists? Which one should be preferred and in what scenarios?
Why do the raii variants require the Context object?

Comment: "*Why do the raii variants require the Context object?*" From that documentation, only one object seems to require the `raii::Context`: the `raii::Instance`. And the docs for `raii::Context` seem to explain why it exists and what it contains.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think that not only the raii::Instance requires it. The Context initializes a dynamic dispatcher that is used by all raii objects. I didn't find a good documentation on what is the proper way to mix non-raii objects with the raii variants, and when it is proper to use the UniqueHandle variant.

Comment: "*I think that not only the raii::Instance requires it.*" You "think"? If an API doesn't take something as a parameter, then either it doesn't need it or it will get what it needs through other means. If the latter is the case (so nothing is being "passed around"), then either `raii::Context` uses reference counting or some other mechanism to ensure that the underlying object is still around for those who need it, or it relies on you keeping it around. And if it is the latter, then the API documentation needs to say this. If it doesn't, then that means its highly likely to be the former case.

Comment: Consider the way Vulkan works directly. A `VkCommandPool` is created from a `VkDevice`; it relies on the device's continued existence. However, Vulkan's API spells this out very clearly: "Prior to destroying a device, an application is responsible for destroying/freeing any Vulkan objects that were created using that device as the first parameter of the corresponding vkCreate* or vkAllocate* command." Is there a similar statement in `raii::Context`'s documentation?